# Google Places not working after app is published on playstore

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-places-api

I have this situation:

I registered the app with the new Google billing process and generated API key as following instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=vswin

I put my debug sha-1 and also the sha-1 key from the release `.keystore` both with the correct package name. If I do the process this way I get this error:

```
"{\n   \"error_message\" : \"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address xx.xx.xx.xx, with empty referer\",\n   \"predictions\" : [],\n   \"status\" : \"REQUEST_DENIED\"\n}\n"
```

After this I changed restrictions to None (removed android restrictions) and on the debug the application is working, but after publishing the search suddenly stop working.

Comment: because you have to add stores `SHA1` in the maps console

Comment: have you tried the sha1 from play store console. It is present in app signing section.

Comment: @AbdulKawee I have added the sha-1 as explained.

Comment: and your signing release SHA1

Comment: @AnirudhSharma do you mean in app signing in google play console?

Comment: please update SHA1 key of release build on google project

Comment: As I say here: *I put my debug sha-1 and also the sha-1 key from the release .keystore*

Comment: yes from app signing

Comment: Please Regenerate sha(release) form same .keystore which have you used for uploading  apk to playstore. Now past latest sha and try.

Comment: You cant upload an apk with different sha on google play store